# Selenium Chrome Driver: Javascript on click function. element not visible or nothing happens

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, airwatch

So I'm working on a script at work that automates VMWare's Airwatch token generation for MDM. It was functioning, but they updated the server/Airwatch Console and this javascript onclick function broke it. I've already searched through various forums and posts and have no luck getting it to work. 
If I have selenium find the element and .click() on it, I get the not visible/not interactable error.
Currently, I have:

```
addButton=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.add.profile.small")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(addButton).perform().click(addButton)
```

And no errors occur but it doesn't do anything.

When manually moving the mouse over the button it changes to a hand instead of the pointer and the button background color changes.

Here's a snippet of the element properties:

```
        <a class="add profile small" onclick="F5_r2u();F5_Event_common(event);
    try{return(eval(F5_Invoke_eval_event(null,F5_jsBody(function(){addTagRow(this);
        }))))}finally{try{F5_Event_finally(event)}catch(e){}}">Add</a>

selector: #\31 34364e7_Tag_Plural > a
xpath: //*[@id="134364e7_Tag_Plural"]/a
```

Any Advice?

Pretty sure I need to have Selenium hover over the button, then click on it, or execute the javascript. Not sure how to do that though.

[Screenshot of Add Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMUw1.png)

Answer (score 0):

when you switch from tab `User` to `Tags` it need to wait until `ADD` button visible

```
# click tab Tags
tabTags = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tab.tags.selector').click()
# wait until visible
addButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.add.profile.small')))
addButton.click()
```

using ActionChains maybe like this

```
tabTags = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tab.tags.selector')
addButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.add.profile.small")

actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(tabTags)
actions.click(addButton)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Should've stated this in the initial post, but I have an implicitlyWait set to 10 for the whole script

Comment: `implicitlyWait` and `WebDriverWait` is different. you need to add demo page or url in the initial post because I think its dynamic page

Comment: Ah okay. Didn't know that. I'll try that on Monday then. Thanks!

Comment: The site isn't public, so I can't share the URL. It is a dynamic page.

Comment: Still no luck. It gets a timeout error with the webDriverWait set to 20, and an element not interactable anytime I have it click on it without the webdriverwait

Comment: can't help without knowing the html structure